# Opearation may be undefined in C

Tags: c, macros

I have macros like:

```
#define INCREMENT(ip) *ip++
#define RETAIN(ip) *ip
```

and in code, I use them like:

```
*op |= INCREMENT(ip)<<15;
*op |= INCREMENT(ip)<<20 | RETAIN(ip);
```

My issue is, I do not get any warning for first line where as I get a warning:

> "operation on ‘*ip’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]"

for second line.

What is it going wrong?

How should I change my macro to avoid that warning?

Note: I have several statements in code which use macros. I can't change all of them(tidious task). So, please tell me the perfect way of writing macro to avaoid that warning.

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: Undefined behaviour: which value of `*ip` will be the operand of `RETAIN(ip)`?

Comment: Why are you using macros in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
*op |= INCREMENT(ip)<<20 | RETAIN(ip);
```

is preprocessed into

```
*op |= *ip++ << 20 | *ip;
```

As there is no sequence point between the `*ip++ << 20`and `*ip`, the postincrement of `ip` can be sequenced either before or after evaluation of `*ip`. So the operation has an undefined behavior.

And as a side note: To avoid other(unrelated) troubles ([Macro Pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html)), replace the macro definitions with these:

```
#define INCREMENT(ip) (*(ip)++)
#define RETAIN(ip) (*(ip))
```

Comment: Got it! Can you suggest the way of writing macro for this so as to avoid the warning?

Comment: @user2582701 It's not just a warning. It is actual error. And..you have to answer yourself - do you want `ip` to get incremented before or after `RETAIN`?

Comment: I have changed the macros as suggested, but still the warnings persist!!

Comment: You cannot fix this by changing the macro. You need to introduce a sequence point to make the behavior defined. Either `tmp = RETAIN(ip); *op |= INCREMENT(ip)<<20 | tmp` or `tmp = INCREMENT(ip); *op |= tmp<<20 | RETAIN(ip)` will work depending on which thing you want to happen first

Comment: @user2582701 As I said, the last suggestion is to avoid *other unrelated* problems.

Answer (score 2):

When second example is expanded it becomes

```
*op |= *ip++ << 20 | *ip;
```

Here it is undefined whether value of **second** `*ip` is read before or after `ìp` is incremented.

Comment: Yeah!! Can you suggest the correct way of writing macro so as to avoid the warning?